# Is it best to avoid all interactions with disreputable or predatory conferences?

Tags: conference, publishers, disreputable-publishers

Potentially predatory publishers and journals (as listed on Beall’s list [here](http://scholarlyoa.com/2012/10/22/science-target-targeting-your-author-fees/)) are springing up more and more often, but they do not always stick to journals and publishing articles. Some host conferences, workshops, or other events with reputable chairs and directors.

If the publishing agency behind a conference is fishy or believed to be predatory, but the conference it hosts is chaired by reputable names, is it still best to avoid the conference?

Has anyone had experience going to a conference or workshop like this?

Comment: Re: *conference it hosts is chaired by reputable names* : note that one of Beall's possible criteria for listing a publisher as predatory is "includes scholars on an editorial board without their 
knowledge or permission" (or, includes scholars on conference committee without same). Do these "reputable names" mention this conference on their own web pages? Are you sure they know they are listed as chairs?

Comment: I have emailed one of the chairs asking a question about the conference, so I am waiting for a reply. I've done a bit of googling and it doesn't seem like there are any references to the conference on either chair's professional website. It is definitely not looking bright!

Comment: Update: I have emailed both chairs now, still awaiting a reply.

Comment: There's a rather vivid write-up from an attendee of an OMICS conference at: http://scholarlyoa.com/2013/09/12/conference-attendee-to-omics-i-want-out/#more-2225. Obviously, this experience might not be repeated at other conferences, but it gives an idea of how things might go.

Comment: Very interesting write-up: thank you for that.

Update: No response from either chair...

Answer (score 7):

Publishing in predatory journals looks bad on your resume.  It suggests that your work was not good enough to publish in a respected journal/conference, and, frankly, you're better off *not* publishing the work.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you spend your time and money to attend one when there is no shortage of good, legitimate conferences?  Your time is valuable.  Stay away from anything that you even suspect might not be first-rate.